# Table View To Custom View Controller?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I Wanted to know if I have two cells in a tableview, and I want that if i click the first cell it seagues to specific view controller, and if I click the second cell it seagues to another view controller.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0 :
        println("First cell")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case 1 :
        println("Second Cell")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        println("No cell selectd")
    }
}
```

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=14494718269977991622) is your sample project.

Comment: I have added sample project.

Comment: Hey! @DharmeshKheni, It worked, but when I get to the View controller, I can't go Back. How do I go Back. I tried embedding in navigation view controller but even that didn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: You can add navigationBar programmatically.

Comment: How can I add navigation Bar programmatically?

Comment: Sorry but could you please tell me how. I couldn't find on Google, or rather couldn't understand that way. Thanks.

Comment: Check this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=65798250404426534672

Comment: Sorry but this is not what i was asking. I meant to say when I click the Cell 1 it goes to FirstViewController(which is perfectly fine), But there is **no back button** which leads back to the TableView. Sorry For troubling you once again.

Comment: I already added back button into fristView thats not what you want?

Comment: No there is no back button in first view, rather no first view only(the second project is what i am talking about).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81104/discussion-between-dreamjar-and-dharmesh-kheni).

Answer (score 0):

Call `performSegue:withIdentifier:` from the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in your view controller. You can conditionally call segues with different identifiers in your code.